# Count column in Pivot Table with same column index

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I have searched online a lot but was not able to find the solution for the error.

**Code**

```
        AreaReference areaRef = new AreaReference("A1:T"+ sheet.getLastRowNum());
        CellReference cellRef = new CellReference("A2");
        XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = summarysheet.createPivotTable(areaRef,cellRef,sheet);
        pivotTable.addRowLabel(19);
        pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 19);
```

**Problem:** I am trying to add the RowLabel on index 19 and also trying to count column 19.

After I run, It shows an error that file is corrupted. But when i change the index in addColumnLabel. It works.

Any suggestions or recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

so the problem here is when you set row label to column say 19, it won't set it as data field, and when you do a count on the same column it fails, quick fix is to set that particular column not only to be as axisRow but also data field by

```
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 19);
pivotTable.addRowLabel(19);
pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(19).setDataField(true);
```

give it a try!!!